# Infinitly long round rectangle

Tags: language-agnostic

Basically my goal is for my page content div to be encapsulated in a round rectangle. Sort of like this:

```
Top of round rect (White)
Page content (uses a white rectangular css background) 
Bottom of round rect(White)
```

So then the page content section can be as long as I need and retain the round rect shape. I'm just not sure the best way to do this. I tried adding an img to the top of pagecontent div, but the transparent areas were overridden by the pagecontent's background. Thanks

Comment: I see this is already on doctype.com http://doctype.com/infinitly-long-round-rectangle

Comment: I didn't get an answer there, and I could not find anything on this on Google

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you mean you should put the top and bottom divs outside of the content div :

```
<html>
<div id=top>&nbsp;</div>
<div id=middle>

... insert page content ...

</div>
<div id=bottom>&nbsp;</div>
</html>
```

and then in the css

```
#top {
 background : url("top.png") no-repeat bottom center;
 height : <height of image in pixels>px;
 padding : 0;
 margin: 10px auto 0 auto;
 width:<required width>
}

#middle {
 background : url("middle.png") repeat-y top center;
 padding : 0;
 margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
 width:<required width>
}

#bottom {
 background : url("bottom.png") no-repeat top center;
 height : <height of image in pixels>px;
 padding : 0;
 margin: 0 auto 10px auto;
 width:<required width>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The famous [Sliding Doors](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/slidingdoors/) technique may be what you need.  You may need to add an additional repeating image to make it infinitely long.